# phpBB - two forum views on one board?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phpbb3

Trying to create a scenario in phpBB when a logged in user clicks a link or button (which I can put in the header file), one set of forums is displayed. When user clicks another link in the header, another set of forums displays. I have a large phpBB board, and need to have it where one view shows 15 forums, and then a second views shows the other 15 forums. This would be good for really large boards.

An idea I had was to set up a phpBB usergroup (for example, usergroupF). This usergroup would have permissions set to be accessible for forum view 2 (15 out of the 30 forums on board), but not to forum view 1 (the other 15 out of 30 forums).

So if a user was in usergroupF, they could see the 15 or so forums in forum view 2, but not see the 15 or so forums in forum view 1.

So, when a visitor first sees board, or when user first logs in, they first see forum view 1. If they click on a special link, they are given temporary existence as a member of usergroupF. For this user, forum view 2 would now be visible, but not forum view 1.

Then they click on the link again and their existence as a member of usergroupF would be removed, and they would only see forum view 1.

When I am referring to a link, I mean something that could be simply be put into the over_header.html file of the theme. As far as what could create this switching of usergroups, it seems like a jQuery snippet may be the way to go. For example, I found a simple tutorial here:
http://www.randomsnippets.com/2011/10/09/how-to-hide-or-show-content-based-on-links-or-urls-via-javascript-jquery/

All the query would do is add user to usergroupF, or remove the user from usergroupF.

Two different versions of the script could be created - one to add the user to usergroupF, and one to remove the user from usergroupF. These could be shown depending on if the user was a member of usergroupF, using simple phpBB if statements, so only one link would be visible at a time.

The end result would be a huge board, with 30 forums, could have 2 separate views a user could switch back and fourth between (each with only 15 forums visible). This would be good for membership based sites using phpBB, such as a site integrated with aMember and phpbb.

I guess the question is if it's possible to give a user temporary access to a usergroup, using something such as a jQuery script, or is there a simpler way of creating this. Any suggestions for getting started with this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think this can be done because user groups require logging in as a user and this cannot be done from a URL without also providing a password, and phpBB will not accept a password as a URL argument.